# What is the correct way of defining a hierarchy of objects for storage in a EF6 DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have looked over the EF6 tutorial videos from MS, and while the guy's voice is soothing, I didn't learn much I didn't already figure out on my own.

What is the correct way of defining a series of objects, some belonging to others, for storage and retrieval from a SQL DB.

Here are a few examples to help clarify my question:

Say we have 3 classes, `car`, `door` and `wheel`. `Car` has a `doors` collection and a `wheels` collection.

**Method 1:**

```
DBContext db = new DBContext();

Car car = new Car();
car.Doors.Add(new Door(){ blah blah });
car Wheels.Add(new Wheel(){ blah blah});

db.Cars.Add(car);
```

**Method 2:**

```
DBContext db = new DBContext();

Car car = new Car();
Door door = new Door(){ vehicle = car, blah blah };
Wheel wheel = new Wheel(){ vehicle = car, blah blah };

db.Cars.Add(car);
db.Doors.Add(door);
db.Wheels.Add(wheel);
```

**Method 3:**

```
DBContext db = new DBContext();

Car car = new Car();
db.Cars.Add(car);
db.SaveChanges();

Door door = new Door(){ carId= db.cars.Find(*index*), blah blah };
db.Doors.Add(door);
db.SaveChanges();

Wheel wheel = new Wheel(){ vehicle = db.cars.Find(*index*), blah blah };
db.Wheels.Add(wheel);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I realize method 3 seems crazy, but you get the point.

I ask this question mainly because I'm getting this error:

```
Entities in 'DBContext.Beds' participate in the 'LocationBed' relationship. 0 related 'Location' were found. 1 'Location' is expected.
```

..and also because I'm really not used to the model-first approach, I have trouble not viewing the model as a 1-1 representation of the database.